# Why does require-handlebars-plugin ship with its own versions of Underscore, Handlebars, etc.?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Recently ran a Bower update for require-handlebars-plugin and found this at the beginning:

```
define([
//>>excludeStart('excludeHbs', pragmas.excludeHbs)
  'hbs/handlebars', 'hbs/underscore', 'hbs/i18nprecompile', 'hbs/json2'
//>>excludeEnd('excludeHbs')
], function (
//>>excludeStart('excludeHbs', pragmas.excludeHbs)
  Handlebars, _, precompile, JSON
//>>excludeEnd('excludeHbs')
) {
```

Why is this the plugin shipping with its own versions of Handlebars, Underscore, etc.?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question from the plugin makers!